# Where are you flying to? vs Where are you going to fly?

Tags: difference, synonyms

Why is it so common for the attendant to ask at airports during check-in ''Where are you flying to?'' instead of ''Where are you going to fly?''

Comment: Because, if you are in an airport, your method of going to your destination is far more likely to be by **flying in an airplane** rather than by riding in an oxcart.

Answer (score 1):

These (very much standardized) dialogs are used because they're asking about the *destination*, and the hanging preposition (though questionable by purists) invites one to answer "**to** Amsterdam," or whatever location.

"Where are you going to fly?" is a bit ambiguous: "At the airport," "From Tashkent," "In an airplane?", or "To Boring, Oregon," are all responsive replies to that question.